# unable to upload a photo to a facebook page timeline using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a PHP app which interacts with facebook. I'm successfully able to post a photo to user wall , uswer timeline and to the wall of a facebook page, but when i try to post the same photo to facebook page timeline it throws an error "**invalid appsecret_proof parameter**".
i commented out the code that tries to set the appsecret_proof in base_facebook.php file and then tried running the app it gave "**The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**" error.
i have given 'photo_upload , publish_stream , publish_actions , manage_pages , user_photos'  permissions to the app . i have set the access token of the page before making the following call

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api ( '/page_id/feed' , 'POST' , array(  
                                                'source'  => $photo ,
                                                'message' => $message ,
                                                'name' => 'vinay' ,
        ) );
```

how do i resolve this?

edit : i have also disabled the "Require AppSecret Proof for Server API calls" in the app advanced settings

Comment: Photos are to be posted against `page_id/photos`, not `page_id/feed` [according to docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos).

Comment: using page_id/photos i'm able to post to page's timeline, how do i post to page album or to the news feed such that the photo appears in page's home.

Comment: By posting against `/album_id/photos` …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos

Comment: yes, but shouldn't page_id/photos do the same thing as album_id/photos, according to facebook doc if no album id is specified app should create an album and post the photos to the album

Comment: CBroe just answered to your ques: `how do i post to page album`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post to a specific album, use `/album_id/photos` and if you don't care of any album simply use: `/page_id/photos`.

Now, if you use the **user access token**, the photo will be uploaded on that page (in either of the above two cases), but it will appear in the page wall under the section:

> *Recent Posts by Others on PageName*

If you want your photo to be visible on the page's timeline; the photo must be published on behalf of the page itself- using the **page access token**, not the user access token.

To get the page access token query for: `/me/accounts` with permission: `manage_pages`. [Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Daccess_token)

Comment: ya i have tried uploading the photo using page access token (mentioned in the question) that's what leading me to invalid appsecret_proof parameter error

Comment: Have you checked out this dicussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683421/why-do-i-get-invalid-appsecret-proof-provided-in-the-api-argument ?

Comment: But you said that you are able to publish photo using `page_id/photos` in your second comment?

Comment: yes i have checked the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683421/why-do-i-get-invalid-appsecret-proof-provided-in-the-api-argument .

Comment: ok let me just summarise : i'm able to upload to user timeline , user album , page timeline : all these using the user access token , what is left to be done is posting (if possible) to page album so that it appears on page's home

Comment: that means the page access token is not used correctly, use the page token with your call itself, like other parameter `'access_token' => 'PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN'` and try out your call with [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)