# facebook graph api calls with appsecret_proof in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, app-secret

What is the right way of making graph api calls with appsecret_proof parameter in python? Is there any library that allows such thing?

I was trying to use 'python for facebook' library but the documentation is literally nonexistent so I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how you could do that using the [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk):

```
import facebook
import hashlib
import hmac

def genAppSecretProof(app_secret, access_token):
    h = hmac.new (
        app_secret.encode('utf-8'),
        msg=access_token.encode('utf-8'),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    )
    return h.hexdigest()

app_secret = "xxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxx"
api = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
msg = "Hello, world!"
postargs = {"appsecret_proof": genAppSecretProof(app_secret, access_token)}
status = api.put_wall_post(msg, postargs)
```

Tested with Python 2.7.9 and facebook-sdk 1.0.0-alpha.

Comment: I tried to follow your example but it didn't work. I fixed it by replacing:

`status = api.put_wall_post(msg, postargs)`

with:

`status = api.put_wall_post(msg, appsecret_proof=genAppSecretProof(access_token))`

Comment: @haeger: If I paste your code in my example I get a `TypeError: genAppSecretProof() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.
If I add the missing parameter it results in a `TypeError: put_wall_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'appsecret_proof'`.

What python and facebook-sdk versions do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this without the facebook SDK  quite simple... the key  is that your `facebook_app_token` is a concatenation if your `app_id` and `app_secret` combined with a `|`.

```python
import hmac,hashlib
facebook_app_id     = '<YOUR_APP_ID>'
facebook_app_secret = '<YOUR_APP_SECRET>'
facebook_app_token  = '{}|{}'.format(facebook_app_id,facebook_app_secret)
app_secret_proof    = hmac.new(facebook_app_secret.encode('utf-8'),
                           msg=facebook_app_token.encode('utf-8'),
                           digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Then you can include the app_secret_proof in whatever API you're calling... e.g.,

```python
import requests
base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<USER_ID>/ids_for_pages?access_token={}&appsecret_proof={}'
url = base_url.format(facebook_app_token,app_secret_proof)
result = requests.get(url)
result.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is too old, but I found other way to generate `app_secret_proof` using this  [python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk).

```
    from facebook_business import session
    fb_session = session.FacebookSession(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
    app_secret_proof = fb_session.appsecret_proof
```