# How to post to facebook page directly from php sdk without login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I don't know how to configure for facebook sdk. I just do with google search instruction. But I always get this error finally of every error fix. I use latest facebook php sdk from facebook official page..I find this error on google..
this is facebook link post example.. i just do testing multiple ways..Or May you explain how to configure out facebook php sdk..Thank

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/Facebook.php';
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\autoload;
use Facebook\Exception;


$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'my-app-id',
    'app_secret' => 'my-app-secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

 /* $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
  try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} */
  //var_dump($fb);
 // $fb->setExtendedAccessToken();

// Get access short live access token
$accessToken ='REMOVED';
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
  var_dump($response);die;
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message
> 'Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument' in
> C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException.php:100
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(210):
> Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse))
>
> ## 1 C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(255):
>
> Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException() #2
> C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(82):
> Facebook\FacebookResponse->decodeBody() #3
> C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\FacebookClient.php(225):
> Facebook\FacebookResponse->__construct(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest),
> '{"error":{"mess...', 400, Array) #4
> C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\Facebook.php(504):
> Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest))
>
> ## 5 C:\wamp\www\facebook-php in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0\src\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException.php
>
> on line 100

Comment: never post access tokens, and use google to search for error messages.that one surely gets you some results.

Comment: first time you login with facebook and get access Tokens use the access token and send data, without access Tokens it's not possible.

Comment: The error message 'Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument' should give you the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18690810/405525